# Insert <tr> in a table after every third loop

Tags: php, woocommerce, html-table

I've edited WooCommerce template so the output of variation labels will be in the same tr and variation values will be in the same tr accordingly.

So far it works fine but i want to change tr after the third td-loop.

This is my php:

```
<table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <?php $labels = $values = ''; ?>
        <?php $loop = 0; foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_name => $options ) : $loop++; ?>
        <?php 
            $swatches = theme_has_swatches( $product->get_id(), $attribute_name, $options, $available_variations, $swatches_use_variation_images);
            $active_variations = theme_get_active_variations( $attribute_name, $available_variations );
        ?>

        <?php ob_start(); ?>
        <td class="label" style="padding-right: 15px;min-width: 175px;"><label for="<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ); ?>"><?php echo wc_attribute_label( $attribute_name ); ?></label></td>
        <?php $labels .= ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean(); ?>
        <?php ob_start(); ?>
        <td class="value <?php if ( ! empty( $swatches ) ): ?>with-swatches<?php endif; ?>" style="padding-right: 15px;min-width: 175px;">
        <?php if ( ! empty( $swatches ) ): ?>
            <div class="swatches-select swatches-on-single" data-id="<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ); ?>">
            <?php
                if ( is_array( $options ) ) {
                    if ( isset( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . $attribute_name ] ) ) {
                                                $selected_value = $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . $attribute_name ];
                    } elseif ( isset( $selected_attributes[ $attribute_name ] ) ) {
                                                $selected_value = $selected_attributes[ $attribute_name ];
                    } else {
                                                $selected_value = '';
                    }

                    // Get terms if this is a taxonomy - ordered
                    if ( taxonomy_exists( $attribute_name ) ) {

                        $terms = wc_get_product_terms( $product->get_id(), $attribute_name, array( 'fields' => 'all' ) );

                        $swatch_size = theme_wc_get_attribute_term( $attribute_name, 'swatch_size' );

                        $_i = 0;
                        $options_fliped = array_flip( $options );
                        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                        if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, $options ) ) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        $key = $options_fliped[$term->slug];

                        $style = '';
                        $class = 'theme-swatch swatch-on-single ';

                        $class .= ' swatch-size-' . $swatch_size;

                        if ( $selected_value == $term->slug ) {
                            $class .= ' active-swatch';
                        }

                        echo '<div class="' . esc_attr( $class ) . '" data-value="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '" ' . selected( sanitize_title( $selected_value ), sanitize_title( $term->slug ), false ) . ' style="' . esc_attr( $style ) .'">' . apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name ) . '</div>';

                        $_i++;
                        }

                    } else {

                        foreach ( $options as $option ) {
                            $class = '';

                            if ( $selected_value == $option ) {
                                $class .= ' active-swatch';
                            }

                            if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_hide_out_of_stock_items' ) && $active_variations ) {
                                if ( in_array( $term->slug, $active_variations ) ) {
                                    $class .= ' swatch-enabled';
                                } else {
                                    $class .= ' swatch-disabled';
                                }
                            }

                            echo '<div class="' . esc_attr( $class ) . '" data-value="' . esc_attr( sanitize_title( $option ) ) . '" ' . selected( sanitize_title( $selected_value ), sanitize_title( $option ), false ) . '>' . esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $option ) ) . '</div>';
                        }

                    }
                }
            ?>

            </div>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php
                wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options( array(
                    'options'   => $options,
                    'attribute' => $attribute_name,
                    'product'   => $product,
                ) );
                echo end( $attribute_keys ) === $attribute_name ? wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_reset_variations_link', '<a class="reset_variations" href="#">' . esc_html__( 'Clear', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>' ) ) : '';
            ?>

            </td>
            <?php $values .= ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean(); ?>      
            <?php endforeach;?>
            <?php echo '<tr>', $labels,  '</tr><tr>', $values, '</tr>'; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I've tried to set  `$_i = 1` and the following statement but it didn't work.
What am i doing wrong?

```
if ($_i % 3 == 0){
   echo "</tr><tr>";
}
$_i++;
```

Comment: It can be useful to mention which template file you are modifying, (variable.php). 
Also which code lines you have changed: (34 - 54) 
Have you tried to debug or print $_i? so you can see if this actually works during the loop?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Based on this post https://www.damiencarbery.com/2017/11/change-woocommerce-variations-layout/ i've edit the variable.php file of WooCommerce by using the `ob_start` function and by adding  the following code `<?php $labels = $values = ''; ?>` `<?php echo '<tr>', $labels,  '</tr><tr>', $values, '</tr>'; ?>` .

Answer (score 1):

You must use a division of 3 modulo.

Like this:

```
  if($loop % 3 == 0) {
     //if true...
  }
```

Comment: Using "==" however isn't what you should do ;)

Comment: Why not? Yes, he could use "===". @maio290

Comment: @AleksiVirtanen can you edit your answer on how should i edit my php code? It doesn't seem to work.